# Angular-cli , Karma, "you may need an appropriate loader ___Karma___: ANY

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-runner, angular2-cli

I am having an issue using the angular-cli with Karma for unit testing an angular 2 application, I was able to get protractor working fine for e2e testing.

**I run ng test and here is what I get**

[angular2 karma error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVH5i.jpg)

I am running ng test within an angular2 application that was not initialized the angular-cli.  I believe the issue revolves around tsconfig.json some how.

I have initialized an angular2 application with angular-cli via ng init and when I run that application with ng test it works fine, I believe the tsconfig is the issue with hammerjs and the other js dependencies somehow interfering.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Karma.conf.js:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './app/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './app/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: '../angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "../wwwroot/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base ui/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@angularclass/request-idle-callback": "^1.0.7",
    "@angularclass/webpack-toolkit": "^1.3.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.7",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.10",
    "codelyzer": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "parse5": "^1.3.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.8",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my angular-cli.json

```js
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "name": "core"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "app",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./ui/protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./ui/karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

here is my webpack.common.js

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
var ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'CORE',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

module.exports = function(options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {
  
    metadata: METADATA,
    
    entry: {

      'polyfills': './ui/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'vendor': './ui/vendor.browser.ts',
      'main': './ui/boot.ts'
    },
    
    resolve: {      
      extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.scss', '.css', '.less'],
      modules: [helpers.root('ui'), 'node_modules'],

    },
    
    module: {

      preLoaders: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'string-replace-loader',
          query: {
            search: '(System|SystemJS)(.*[\\n\\r]\\s*\\.|\\.)import\\((.+)\\)',
            replace: '$1.import($3).then(mod => (mod.__esModule && mod.default) ? mod.default : mod)',
            flags: 'g'
          },
          include: [helpers.root('ui')]
        },

      ],
      
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
                // Font Definitions
        //{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
        //{ test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
        //{ test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
        //{ test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
        //{ test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },

        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loaders: [
            '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
            'awesome-typescript-loader',
            'angular2-template-loader'
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },

        //{
        //    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        //    loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
        //},
         { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
         //{ test: /bootstrap\/dist\/css\/umd\//, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
        
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loaders: ['style','to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        //{
        //    test: /\.scss$/,
        //    exclude: /node_modules/,
        //    loader: 'raw-loader!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        //},
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
        },
        
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('ui/index.html')]
        },
        
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          loader: 'file'
        }
      ],

      postLoaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'string-replace-loader',
          query: {
            search: 'var sourceMappingUrl = extractSourceMappingUrl\\(cssText\\);',
            replace: 'var sourceMappingUrl = "";',
            flags: 'g'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer],

    plugins: [      
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          $: 'jquery',
          jquery: 'jquery',
          "window.Tether": 'tether',
          'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
          'window.$': 'jquery',
      }),

       //new ProvidePlugin({
       //    jQuery: 'jquery',
       //    $: 'jquery',
       //    jquery: 'jquery',
       //    "window.Tether": 'tether'
       //}),
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('ui') // location of your src
      ),

      new CleanWebpackPlugin(
                [
                    './wwwroot/dist',
                    //'./wwwroot',
                ]
            ),
      
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
          from: 'ui/assets',
        to: 'assets'
      }]),

      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'ui/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),
      
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

    ],

  };
}
```

here is my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./ui",
    "paths": {},
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",      
      "node",      
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

here is my test.ts

```js
import '../polyfills.browser.ts';

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};


Promise.all([
  System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
  System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
])
  // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
  .then(([testing, testingBrowser]) => {
    testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
      testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );
  })
  // Then we find all the tests.
  .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
  // And load the modules.
  .then(context => context.keys().map(context))
  // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```

here is my polyfil.browsers.ts

```js
// TODO(gdi2290): switch to DLLs

// Polyfills

// import 'ie-shim'; // Internet Explorer 9 support


// import 'core-js/es6';
// Added parts of es6 which are necessary for your project or your browser support requirements.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
// see issue https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/709
// import 'core-js/es6/promise';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
import 'ts-helpers';

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production


} else {
  // Development

  Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');

}
```